# ASP.NET MVC request forwarder

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes, requesthandler

I would like to achieve this kind of functionality:

When a client makes GET request to

GET http://www.myserviceurl.com/rest/facebook/profile/me

to get response from

GET http://graph.facebook.com/profile/me

Application logic will append all nessesary parameters so the final url will look like:

graph.facebook.com/profile/me?access_token=XXX

Similar,

POST myserviceurl.com/rest/twitter/statuses/update.json
with post data
status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk&trim_user=true&include_entities=true

->

POST api.twitter.com/1/statuses/update.json
with POST data
status=Maybe%20he%27ll%20finally%20find%20his%20keys.%20%23peterfalk&trim_user=true&include_entities=true

This way I want to create a layer of apstraction and allow my clients to invoke my rest service  using the same structure of provider rest url.

What will be a recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You could use [Facebook C# SDK](http://csharpsdk.org/) (which is basically a wrapper for Facebook Graph API) to  fetch json data from Facebook and return it to Your users.